# LINQ find records with no join

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following LINQ query:

```
vm.Ter = (from tr in DataContext.Terr_Rp
          join dm in DataContext.Dt_Mrs
          on tr.T_ID equals dm.D_ID + "00" 
          select tr).ToList();
```

I need to find the ones that do not have a match. Meaning there is no join.
I tried not equals but C# has a problem with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `!Any()` should do the trick.

```
vm.Ter = (from tr in DataContext.Terr_Rp
          where !DataContext.Dt_Mrs.Any(dm => tr.T_ID == dm.D_ID + "00")
          select tr).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list1 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6};
var list2 = new List<int>{5,6,7,8,9,10};

var result = from l1 in list1 where !list2.Contains(l1) select l1;

result: {1,2,3,4}
```